# Jquery Button to toggle sql results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, sql

I have a table in the database(myTable) listed as such

```
**Color**          **State**           **Fruit**
  Red                Idaho               Plum
  Blue               Kentucky            Orange
  Yellow             Florida             Cherry
  Green              Hawaii              Apple
  Red                Michigan            grape
  Blue               Alabama             Bannana
  Red                Nevada              Apple
```

I have JQuery Buttons on HTML page where if you click a button it toggles a table that displays the above information

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button" value="Toggle table">Red Colors</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Blue Colors</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yellow Colors</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Orange Colors</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Green Colors</button>
<div class="container">
<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Fruit</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Idaho</td>
    <td>Plum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Kentucky</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yellow</td>
    <td>Florida</td>
    <td>Cherry</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>Hawaii</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Michigan</td>
    <td>grape</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Alabama</td>
    <td>Bannana</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Nevada</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#table{
    display: none;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        $("#table").toggle();
    });
});
```

What i want to happen is i click on the red colors button and a table will show up displaying only the entries with red in its first column. Click on the Blue button that table only displays items with Blue in the Color Column.

I know the sql will go something like this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE color =""
```

Comment: Can you share your back end that will fetch data from sql table?

Comment: Do you want to write code for you?
What you have done in Server side?

Answer (score 1):

In case the table is not very big. You may always get all rows from the server, than filter it on front end. For example add marker class to every `tr` than hide/show it.

```
<table>
  ...
  <tr class='my-red'>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Idaho</td>
    <td>Plum</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
<button class='toggle-red'>Toggle Red</button>
```

JS

```
var redIsOn = true;  
function toggleRed(){
  redIsOn = !redIsOn; 
  $(".my-red").css('display',redIsOn?'block':'none');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle-red").on('click',toggleRed);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="red" value="Toggle table">Red Colors</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="blue">Blue Colors</button>
<div class="container">
<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Fruit</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Idaho</td>
    <td>Plum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Kentucky</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yellow</td>
    <td>Florida</td>
    <td>Cherry</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>Hawaii</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Michigan</td>
    <td>grape</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Alabama</td>
    <td>Bannana</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Nevada</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#red").click(function()
    {
     $('tbody tr:not(:contains("Red"))').not().toggle();   
    });

     $("#blue").click(function()
    {
       $('tbody tr:not(:contains("Blue"))').not().toggle();   
    });
});
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7qbt2voj/

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle here which will flip the table based on color of button chosen.
As of now it is working only on first two button.
rest can be allied similarly

here is the [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0b2m6sfv/)

Code is changed at

`$("#btn_Blue").click(function() {`

On the contrary if you are using sql to get table data in jquery you can follow this :

replacing `color` in script with your sql data 
here is the supporting fiddle : [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c0sdk9b2/)